# How to receive a num at each step and continue until zero is entered; then this program should print each entered num as its own num

Tags: python

Here I have this code:

N = int(input())

Tmp=n

While tmp>0 :

Print(n)

Tmp-=1

But for ex: when I have:

3

2

1

0

As entered nums, it just prints:

3

3

3

But I need to print:

3

3

3

2

2

1

```
Here I have this code:

N = int(input())

Tmp=n

While tmp>0 :
   
  Print(n)

  Tmp-=1
```

But there is a problem!bc it just prints

3

3

3

Instead of:

3

3

3

2

2

1

Answer (score 1):

you need to `print(tmp)` instead of `print(n)`

this will print 3 2 1.
To get 3 3 3 2 2 1 you need to change your code more:

```py
n = int(input())

tmp=n

while tmp > 0:
  for _ in range(tmp)
    print(tmp)
  tmp -= 1
```

Comment: I tried it too but when I entered 1,1,0 as input it just prints 1! Not 1,1

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve then,  the expected input here is 3

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `if` statement when `tmp` equals 0 then subtract `n` by 1 and assign `tmp` back to `n`:

```
n = int(input('input : '))
tmp = n
while tmp > 0:
    print(n)
    tmp -= 1
    if tmp == 0:
        n -= 1
        tmp = n
```

Output:

```
# input : 3
# 3
# 3
# 3
# 2
# 2
# 1
```